# AVAsset dimensions : track's naturalSize is not the size off the exported video

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, avasset

I'm working with AVFoundation, importing videos from the user's library.

I need the real video's dimensions. After making a screen-recording on my iPhone 7, the video size should be *(750.0, 1334.0)*.
When using AVAsset track's naturalSize, I'm always getting *(720.0, 1280.0)*.

How can I get the **real** video dimension ?

Here's the code I'm using :

```
guard let track = tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return .zero }
return track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)
```

Answer (score 4):

The video recorded using an iOS device will be sized according the settings you set on `Settings > Camera > Record Video` and ignoring device's screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks Bruno! But, how do you explain that if I share that screen recording via AirDrop to my Mac, the video dimension is (750.0, 1334.0) ?

Comment: This is the way how iOS exports a video to be sent by AirDrop, even the extension of the file changes from `.mov` to `.mp4`. You can change it using `CGAffineTransform` and as Apples says [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack/1389837-preferredtransform), `The value of this property is often, but not always, identity.`